# GridView - page navigation in PagerTemplate works on a second attempt only

Tags: c#, asp.net, events, gridview, paging

(Apologies in advance for a rookie question)

I have a simple GridView with paging implemented like this:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="ResultsGrid" runat="server" EnableViewState="true"
            AutoGenerateColumns="true" OnDataBound="ResultsGrid_DataBound"
            OnPreRender="ResultsGrid_PreRender" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="25">
            <PagerTemplate>
                <asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="PageSizeDDL" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="PageSizeDDL_SelectedIndexChanged">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="10" Value="10" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="25" Value="25" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="50" Value="50" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="100" Value="100" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Show all" Value="All" />
                </asp:DropDownList>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="PagerPrevious" Text="<" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Previous" OnCommand="Pager_Command" />
                <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="PagerNumbers">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="PagerPageButton" Enabled='<%# Eval("Enabled") %>' Text='<%# Eval("Text") %>'
                            CommandName="Page" CommandArgument='<%# Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Text"))-1 %>'
                            OnCommand="Pager_Command" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="PagerNext" Text=">" CommandName="Page" CommandArgument="Next" OnCommand="Pager_Command" />
            </PagerTemplate>
        </asp:GridView>
```

The selected page size (rows per page), selected page index and total number of rows (retrieved from db) are stored in viewstate.

The order of events is the following:

1. Pager_Command - get the page index to navigate to, set ResultsGrid.PageIndex to the new value;
2. Get data for the next page from database;
3. Store new page size, page index and total number of rows in viewstate;
4. Bind new data to the grid;
5. Update Page linkbuttons (disable previous/next buttons if we are already on the first/last page etc.).

The problem is that when I click on page numbers or previous/next buttons, the Command event for the Page control I am clicking on simply does not fire. It goes to Page_Load on postback, then straight to page render, and the grid shows no rows or a first row of whatever was in it before clicking. THEN, if I click on ANY of Page LinkButtons again, the Command fires this time, picks up correct page index from the previous attempt and the page I was trying to navigate to is loaded.

<s>It looks like I've messed up the order of events at some point, but now I cannot find what exactly causes the issue. Any help would be appreciated!</s>

**Edited:** found it - I've been setting ResultsGrid.PageIndex value twice, before AND after data binding. The second time was what disrupted event order - after removing it everything works like charm.

Comment: Please add code of pageLoad, BindGrid method and PagerCommand so that somebody can understand the exact problem.

Comment: Actually I've found out what was happening (see edit) :) Thank you for asking anyway - that prompted me to go through the whole sequence again and look carefully this time :)